# Android Emulate Device Without Phone Number

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have an android application and I'm able to simulate the network going in and out, however I wish to know if there is a way to simulate an android device without a phone number.

I have a program which can run just through wireless, so the phones don't need service. I'm curious if there is a way to emulate this with the android emulator in eclipse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use the [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) emulator. This emulator doesn't have a telephony module - for example, switching off wifi switches off all network connectivity. The emulator works great for Eclipse, IntelliJ and Android Studio.

And you also get the benefit of having an insanely fast emulator.

Comment: I'm looking into this solution. So far, I installed Geny in a VM with eclipse and it isn't running because it is complaining about the Open GL 2.0 for the video card. I'm checking into option of either upgrading the driver for my VM's video driver and/or trying to run it on my host. We'll see if I have the hardware to use this solution.

Comment: I'm going to accept the answer, so you get the bounty, as it seems others agree with you. The solution unfortunately doesn't work for me at the moment, as my machine doesn't have a graphics card that meets the requirements... pooh...